# Просмотр библиотек Python (.pyd)

Tags: python, импорт, directory

Пытаюсь открыть и посмотреть что внутри библиотек Python. Находил библиотеку с расширением `.pyd`, но когда её открываю, не могу ничего понять, видимо другая кодировка или что-то неправильно делаю.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.pyd` - это [DLL скомпилированная из С-шного исходника](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll). Разумеется, там внутри нет ничего удобочитаемого. Если вы хотите прочитать `pyd`, то нужно искать исходник.

Возьмём к примеру `\python\DLLs\_uuid.pyd`. [Инструкция в `setup.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62bf263a775f4444d8b5d5841cc09be3bd53e933/setup.py#L1851) сообщает, что этот модуль собирается из исходного файла [`_uuidmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_uuidmodule.c). Это код на языке Си, в `_uuid.pyd` только скомпилированный машинный код.

Однако ж подавляющее большинство пакетов python написаны на языке python. Соответственно, у файлов расширение `.py`. О том, как устроены пакеты, [написано в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить исходники модуля, в интерпретаторе Python введите следующее:

```
>>> import os #Импортируйте интресующий вас модуль
>>> os.__file__ #И дайте эту команду (МОДУЛЬ.__file__)
'C:\\Users\\Sokolovy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\os.py'
```

Далее просто перейдите по полученому пути.

Comment: Спасибо большое)